# GPU plugged in, fans spinning, display working, but GPU not showing up in device / task manager

Tags: gpu

as stated in the title, my 650 Ti Boost is plugged into my motherboard, the fans are spinning, everything seems fine. The display is turned on (however bad resolution, and doesn't reach edges of monitor). I looked in device manager, and sure enough, the only display adapter is the default one. This is obviously a driver issue, but the problem is I cannot install any drivers for it without the computer reading it properly. Also, I reset the same PC earlier today, and it was working fine for a while.

Comment: It is not clear in you post why you cannot install the proper driver.

Comment: Download your driver [here](https://www.nvidia.es/Download/index.aspx). It is normal that device manager does not recognize the device without a driver.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The device doesn't need to be recognized for its drivers to be installed. After a successful installation of the drivers, the device will be recognized on the next boot.

Comment: It sounds like the device is working, and you have the Basic Microsoft display adapter installed, time to install the Nvidia drivers.  Everything you explain is perfectly normal for a system without Nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone - I fixed it by updating windows (and I guess it decided to install drivers). The reason I couldn't install them is I downloaded them directly and tried to install, but said that my system wasn't compatible (no extra info). I assumed this meant that since it couldn't detect my GPU, it couldn't install drivers for it, but it probably meant my OS was out of date.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 10 build I used for my initial install was too old to include support for the GPU.  I didn't connect to the Internet during setup.  Once I connected to the internet and ran Windows Update, the graphics card was properly detected.